# How do I change the order of elements using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I know of two ways this can be achieved: Flexbox layout and CSS Table layout. However, **I can't use Flexbox** since I need to support older browsers. **CSS Tables, as far as I know, won't work in my situation**.

I have three block-level elements inside the `<header>` tag. This is the order in which they appear in my HTML source file:

1. `<h1>` heading
2. A logo created using the `<img>` tag
3. A `<div>` which acts like a button

This is the order I wish them to be rendered:

1. Logo first
2. `<h1>` next
3. `<div>` last

Note that the order of the 1st and the 2nd element in the HTML source file need to exchanged when the page is rendered.

Also, I want all three to lie horizontally. This is why **I can't use table-header and table-footer** (as far as I know about them, they can only be used in case of vertical alignment).

**I can't change the order in the HTML source file because of SEO concerns**. Is there another way to achieve the effect I want without using Flexbox?

**I would prefer a non-JavaScript solution**, but if a JS solution can do it without harming the SEO, I'll accept it.

EDIT: Here's my snippet HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>Title
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
  <div id="menu-button"></div>
</header>
```

**The older browsers I am trying to support are: IE8-10. I know Microsoft doesn't support them anymore but over 30% of my target audience uses them.**

One last thing: why is my question being downvoted? Does it violate any StackOverflow rules?

Comment: For `flex` you can use `order` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Please show your HTML as well as describing it.

Comment: What "older browsers" do you need to support?

Comment: A quick but ugly way is to set position:relative; on parent, position:absolute; and left: 0;on the logo. Then adding a margin-right that is as wide as the logo to the h1 text.

Comment: `I can't use Flexbox since I need to support older browsers.`  You might want to look into using polyfills,  don't restrict yourself because of old browsers, it's a life of pain otherwise.. :)  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin As I said, I can't use flex.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have added the HTML but I don't think it will help much. Still if you prefer looking at code.

Comment: @str IE8-10 as my target audience uses them.

Comment: @Keith Thanks!! Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I can't use Flexbox since I need to support older browsers.`

For older browser support, with the flexibility of Javascript pollyfills are a great way to move forward.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Also using something like Babel. https://babeljs.io/  it's also possible to make Javascript more modern too.

Basically the best approach I use nowadays for HTML/Javascript development is assume a modern browser, if older ones are needed polyfill / transpile as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float: left;` on the img to make it move all the way to the left.